# Add fade effect to javascript that shows and hides divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using this javascript to show one div and hide all of the others. It works great. However, I would like to add in a fade effect when the div shows and when the other's disappear.

```
var divState = {};
function showhide(id) {
if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
    //close others
    for (var div in divState) {
        if (divState[div] && div != id) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
            divState[div] = false;
        }
    }
    divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
}
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle with it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/8e8sH/2/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd use http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8e8sH/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-box="box1">Box 1</a> 
<a href="#" data-box="box2">Box 2</a> 
<a href="#" data-box="box3">Box 3</a> 
<a href="#" data-box="box4">Box 4</a>

<div id="hiddendivs">
    <div id="box1" class="box_1">Box 1 Test</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box_2">Box 2 Test</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box_3">Box 3 Test</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box_4">Box 4 Test</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hiddendivs > div {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
#hiddendivs {
    position:relative;
}
.box_1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.box_2 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#6699FF;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.box_3 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#FFFF00;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.box_4 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#00CC99;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddendivs div').not($('#'+$(this).data("box"))).fadeOut();
    $('#' + $(this).data("box")).fadeToggle();
})
```

And as an aside, the CSS can be streamlined further.

Comment: I like this and seems to work good. However, one difference from my original example is that when the "Box 1" link was clicked, the box showed up, but when the same link is clicked a second time, the box goes away. Whereas in your example the box just re-shows on the second click. Is there a way in your example to have the box disappear on a second click?

Comment: Yes, that works great! I'll see if I can implement that onto my page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jquery?  If so, it's as easy as

```
$('#divid1').fadeIn();
$('#divid2').fadeOut();
```

[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

And you can include a parameter for how long you'd like to fading to take.

Comment: I'm new to jquery, is this something I would add to my existing javascript? Or does this require me to use something completely different? I don't want to lose any of my existing functionality, just add in the effect.

Comment: The great thing about jquery is that it's just pure javascript!  So javascript and jquery can coexist side-by-side.  Just include jquery at the top of your html file, and you can start using its functionality.  $('#divid1') is a shortcut to select your element with id="divid1" and give it a bunch of functionality (like fading in and out).  here's the snippet to include at the top of your html: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It's well worth your time reading through the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It takes 1-2 hours in total, and pays off huge dividends.

In this case, replace your assignments to `style.display` with calls to jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.